# Why does black area exist after cropping image?

Tags: php, gd, crop

My code crops image:

```
 function cropimage($x1,$y1,$newwidth, $newheight) {
            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
            imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, $x1, $y1, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
            $this->image = $new_image;
            $this->image->save($file);
        }
```

result:
[image]

Why after cropping the image does black area exist? How to resize it?

Comment: As the manual says in [imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) the third and fourth parameters are for destination x and y, they should be 0 0 and the fifth and sixth should be `$x1` and `$y1` I suppose...

Comment: i had try , but it not ok

Comment: as image result : position crop is correct, it only can't delete black area.

Comment: Is the final image size the correct`cropped` size? or is it the original size?

Comment: Image result: both black area and area image croped is crop size

Answer (score 0):

this code fixed ok:

```
 imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight(), $newwidth, $newheight);
```